# Not quite grasping goroutines and channels, please break this code down

Tags: go

I'm following a quick intro to Go and one of the examples is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func worker(done chan bool) {
    fmt.Print("working...")
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("done")
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    go worker(done)
    <-done
}
```

I understand whats occuring but I guess I'm not grasping the sequence of events or the limitations?

1. A channel is created called `done` with a buffer size of 1.
2. The channel is passed into a function
3. After the timer is complete it adds a `true` boolean to the channel
4. I'm not sure what the final `<-done` is doing though

from: https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization

Comment: `<-done` reads from the channel (and ignores the result)

Comment: so it reads from the channel, but what exactly is it doing with that value or before that value is received?

Comment: Its doing nothing with that value. Its only purpose is to block until the other goroutine writes to the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiver operator `<-` followed by channel name (`done` in this case) is  used to wait for a value written to channel from worker goroutine. (i.e this read operation will be blocking. If you omit `<-done`, main goroutine will exit immediately even before worker's goroutine start and you won't be able to see results)

You can do whatever you want with `<-done` as value: assign it to another variable, pass it as a parameter to another function or just ignore it as in your case... etc.

Comment: "to wait for a value from another goroutine" --- just to read a value from the channel, it has nothing to do with goroutines.

Comment: well it has, worker is executed on a different goroutine from the main goroutine.

Comment: In the OP's code - yes, but your statement "is syntax used by Golang to wait for a value from another goroutine" is generic. So, I pointed out that `<-` is not a syntax to wait for a value from another goroutine. Your answer is not wrong, it's just that statement looks misleading.

Comment: The goroutine that block for reading from a channel is different than the goroutine which involve writing to channel. And i said `<-` FOLLOWED BY CHANNEL NAME is used to wait for a value written to channel in another goroutine which is correct technically and linguistically

Comment: " it has nothing to do with goroutines" ... It has to do the WAITING for value to be written. not just reading it.

Comment: "which is correct technically" --- it's not correct technically, nothing in go requires a value to be written by a different goroutine, you can write by the same goroutine and then read from it. OPs example does it, but "is syntax used by Golang to wait for a value from another goroutine" statement is simply wrong.

Comment: "It has to do the WAITING for value to be written" --- indeed, again: your answer is not wrong, just some of its statements are misleading.

Comment: OK @zerkms ^ ^. I have edited few words.I hope this makes more sense now.